# When your pushes "Enter", An element should be created at the end of another

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make a new element at the end of an element,  for example, I have the element `<div id="elmtobetrig">Element that has to have another element when the user clicks enter nested after this text. <!--Element goes here--></div>`
The code I already tried is here

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="elmtobetrig"></div>
    <script>document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      document.querySelector("div#elmtobetrig").createElement("line").innerHTML = "<br> this should go to the bottom of the element &nbsp; "
    }
  });</script>
```

And I also am aware that you can not `createElement()` to a specific element... is there any way to do what I am trying to?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Comment: @A.Meshu, Thank you, Didn't see JavaScript will say that any invalid element is not rendered/throws an error, also did not see that there is only `document.createElement()`, and not `document.querySelector("someSelector").createElement` and we have to use `appendChild()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not creating the `line` element properly,

- First use [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
- Then use `.innerHTML` to put text in.
- Then use `.append` to add the element.

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="elmtobetrig"></div>
<script>
  document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      let line = document.createElement("line")
      line.innerHTML = "<br> this should go to the bottom of the element &nbsp; "
      document.querySelector("div#elmtobetrig").append(line)
    }
  });
</script>
```

---

### Explanation

The `createElement()` method creates the HTML element specified by tagName, but it **doesn´t append** the element to any parent.

So you need to create the element, set its attributes, and then append it to any parent. If you don´t append it, the element would never be added to the DOM.

Comment: I found an alternative to it but it does work... Thank you